# CodeIgniter mysqli - An Error Was Encountered Invalid DB driver

Tags: codeigniter

if i change dbdriver from mysqli to mysql it's working but not in mysqli
What would be the problem?

database.php - database config

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => FALSE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Give the error detail

Comment: username and password u have not set on above config

Comment: is mysqli php module activated on your xampp / wamp / app server?

Comment: What is the CI version?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure MySQLi Driver is installed and enabled in Apache.

Answer (score 0):

There are three solutions for you

1. Make sure `php-mysqli` is installed and enable in apache.
2. Check System Directory of Codeigniter. If the mysql/mysqli directory not exist at that place then copy it from the fresh codeigniter.
3. Switch the driver from `mysqli` to `pdo`.

   ```
   $active_group = 'default';
   $query_builder = TRUE;
   $db['default'] = array(
     'dsn'   => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=myproject',
     'hostname' => 'localhost',
     'username' => 'root',
     'password' => '*******',
     'database' => 'myproject',
     'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
     'dbprefix' => '',
     'pconnect' => FALSE,
     'db_debug' => FALSE,
     'cache_on' => FALSE,
     'cachedir' => '',
     'char_set' => 'utf8',
     'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
     'swap_pre' => '',
     'encrypt' => FALSE,
     'compress' => FALSE,
     'stricton' => FALSE,
     'failover' => array(),
     'save_queries' => TRUE
   );
   ```

You can follow the full tutorial from the reference article.

https://mytechnode.com/invalid-db-driver-in-codeigniter-mysqli/